# Showing time remaining for a command

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

So I have got this code:

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const config = require("../config.json");
const talkedRecently = new Set();
let coins = require("../coins.json");

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {

  if (message.channel.id === '669657436789014550') {
    if (message.content.indexOf(config.prefix) !== 0) return;

    var minute = 60000;

    if (talkedRecently.has(message.author.id)) {
      message.channel.send(`Ai fost deja într-o explorare. Mai ai de așteptat ` + Math.round((talkedRecently[message.author.id] - Date.now)/minute) + ` minute până să poți merge din nou.`);
    } else {   

      if(!coins[message.author.id]){
        coins[message.author.id] = {
          coins: 0
        };
      }


    let coinAmt = Math.floor(Math.random() * 450) + 1;
    let sCoins = coins[message.author.id].coins;

    var caut = [ //something

    ];

    coins[message.author.id] = {
      coins: coins[message.author.id].coins + coinAmt
    };

    message.channel.send(`**${message.author.tag}**,` +  (caut[Math.floor(Math.random() * caut.length)]))
      .then(() => {
        console.log(`Hopa! Cuiva îi place să meargă-n explorări!`);
      })
    }

    talkedRecently.add(message.author.id);
    setTimeout(() => {
      talkedRecently.delete(message.author.id);
    }, 18000000);
  }
}

module.exports.help = {
    name: 'caut',
    aliases: []
};
```

The thing is It doesnt show how much time remaining does an user has, it shows „NaN” instead of the minutes. Does someone know how can I fix this? It doesnt show any error in console. I thought I have to mention this here.

Comment: looks like you're just adding the message.author.id to the set, which is probably not a value you can subtract date.now from? Maybe have an object where you put the date.now when they last talked in under their message.author id so {"message.author.id is key": Date.Now is value}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be `NaN`, as you aren't adding anything to your `Set` besides the author's id.

Instead of adding an object containing both the id as well as the timestamp, my proposition would be to use a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map):

```js
const talkedRecently = new Map();

if (talkedRecently.has(message.author.id)) {
  // talkedRecently.get(message.author.id) returns the Date object
}

talkedRecently.set(message.author.id, Date.now());
```

Comment: yeah, i tried to do this, but it shows the same thing.

Comment: @ImEzreallyBad My bad, it's `Date.now()`, not `Date.now`. You have the same error in your code.

Comment: nah, it is the same outcome as before. maybe the way im doing it isnt correct? `Math.round((talkedRecently.get(message.author.id) - Date.now)/minute)`

Comment: Like I said, it's `Date.now()`, not `Date.now`. You need to call the method.

Comment: ops mb. Still it shows it 0 and make the countdown like after some time it shows -20 minutes has passed instead of the minutes remaining till the command will be available again. I want it to show „ 240 minutes untill you can explore again”.

Comment: Well, you are subtracting `now` from `then`, not vice-versa, so it would be negative. Please create a new question for any other issues.